# Inequalities involved in the proof of transcendence of $[0,10,10^{2!}, \dots]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, induction, proof-explanation, products

In proof of transcendence of the simple continued fraction $[0,a_1,a_2, \dots]$ in which $a_k=10^{k!}$ (Hardy, et al's *Theory of Numbers*) it uses the following two inequalities:

**i.** $(1+\frac{1}{10})(1+\frac{1}{10^2}) \dots (1+\frac{1}{10^n})<2$ (for all n) and

**ii.** $2 \times 10^{1!+2!+\dots+n!}<10^{2(n!)}$.

How the two mentioned inequalities holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint:

Use $$\ln(1+x)\leq x$$
 By this way we can get that even  $$\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{1}{10^k}\right)<\sqrt[9]e.$$

The second inequality is obviously true by induction.

Good luck!